# Prevent rendering of many async updates to Lexical document

Tags: lexicaljs

I am building an application using the Lexical text editor. The application is built on top of a highly asynchronous graph. Imagine that each node in the Lexical editor is a node that is fetched asynchronously. When I first load the document there are many editor.update(...) calls between asynchronous data fetches. This results in a cascading render-flash as Lexical applies updates between async calls. I would prefer to avoid this and have lexical wait to render until I have finished building the document. There are several ways to approach this but I'm wondering if there are any best practices. For example, maybe build the document in a headless editor and the copy that state over to the rendered editor using SetEditorState.

I do have the option of pre-loading the data and then rendering synchronously but this adds additional complexity that I would prefer to avoid.